# Ширина input, зависящая от ширины модального окна

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, выравнивание

Есть модальное окно

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  display: block;
  z-index: 15;
  /*
  padding-top: 20%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  padding-left: 25%;
  padding-right: 25%;
  */
  /*text-align: center;*/
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.modal-content {
  z-index: 20;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  top: 20%;
  bottom: 10%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 70%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /*
  margin-top: 20%;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%;*/
  margin: auto;
  /*margin-top: 20%;*/
  background-color: #fff;
}

.modal-header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
  position: relative;
}

.closeregwindow {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -25px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.loginsignuptext {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.contentreg {
  /*font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,Roboto,Noto Sans,Ubuntu,Cantarell,Helvetica Neue,sans-serif;*/
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100%;
}

.username {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.inputusername {
  /*
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    */
  width: 100%;
}

.eleminput {
  width: 100%;
}

.modal-body {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="closeregwindow">&times;</span>
      <h2>Вход или регистрация</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="contentreg">
        <p class="username"><b>Имя</b></p>
        <div class="eleminput">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Введите имя пользователя" name="uname" class="inputusername">
        </div>
      </div>
      <p>Какой-то текст в теле модального окна</p>
      <p>Ещё другой текст...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Футер модального окна</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

1. Почему `input` не занимает всю ширину окна? Почему атрибут `width` неправильно работает?
2. У input-а есть ширина, равная `$('.modal-content').width - 2*marginside`. Как задать ширину `input` в `css`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите, чтобы инпут просто не вылазил за рамки экрана, задайте ему ширину 100%. Также, чтобы все бордеры и отступы элемента входили в этот размер, то ему (или всем элементам, как часто делают) необходимо добавить box-sizing: border-box. И могу предположить, что в элементе `eleminput` нет особой необходимости.

```
   * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
     }
    
   .inputusername {
       width: 100%;
     }
```

Если же вы хотите указать конкретный размер инпута, задайте просто, к примеру:

```
.inputusername {
    width: 100px;
 }
```

Если же хотите чтобы он был по центру, можно добавить (хотя вариантов масса):

```
.inputusername {
    width: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
 }
```

Ну и если же хотите, чтобы и инпут и предыдущий элемент `<p>` тоже был по центру, можно задать родительскому блоку, к примеру:

```
.contentreg {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Так же могу посоветовать не использовать размер строго 50% от ширины экрана для модального окна. На маленьких и больших экранах будет не очень весело за этим наблюдать. Для большей отзывчивости можно задать например ширину в 90%, но ограничить `max-width`, допустим 400px. А для того, чтобы центрировать по центру экрана можно использовать `transform: translate()`.

```
.modal-content {
    z-index: 20;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 15px;
    position: absolute;    
    width: 90%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    max-width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: я изменил код в вопросе. Но это не помогло. возникла новая проблема - input не занимает всю ширину окна (несмотря на `width: 100%`)?

Comment: В примере, который вы выложили, если запустите его, то увидите что занимает, даже если раскрыть на весь экран. Что вы у себе на сайте сделали - я не могу знать.

Answer (score 0):

Оберните input в div

```
 <div class="input">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Введите имя пользователя" name="uname" class="inputusername" size="100%">
        </div>
```

И в css

```
input {
    width: 100%;  
}
```

И настройте margin/padding
Чтобы слева и справа были одинаковые расстояния